# windows store adding files in zip archieve dynamically

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, zip, compression

I have got a code from this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/515704/Archive-Multiple-Files-In-Zip-Extract-Zip-Archive

that compresses and extracts a file in zip format.

However the compressing part in the code just creates an empty zipfile, so how can i add files programmatically in this zip archieve?

i have checked the doc for the ziparchieve class and it has a method for .net called CreateEntryFromFile(String, String) , however this method doesn't apply for .net windows store version.

this is the code we are concerned with:

```
private async void ZipClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
FileSavePicker picker = new FileSavePicker();
picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Zip Files (*.zip)", new List<string> { ".zip" });
picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
picker.SuggestedFileName = "1";
zipFile = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();

using (var zipStream = await zipFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        foreach (var file in storeFile)
        {
            ZipArchiveEntry entry = zip.CreateEntry(file.Name);

            using (Stream ZipFile = entry.Open())
            {
                byte[] data = await GetByteFromFile(file);
                ZipFile.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood the sample code, it actually can archive the the files you pass it for the first time, but i'm not sure if the same method can be used to add to add other files in the same zip file later.

```
  public async void zipit(StorageFile zipFile, StorageFile file)
    {
     using (var zipToOpen = await zipFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
            {
                ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry(file.Name);
                using (Stream writer = readmeEntry.Open())
                {
                    //writer.WriteLine("Information about this package.");
                    //writer.WriteLine("========================");
                    byte[] data = await GetByteFromFile(file);
                    writer.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

where "zipFile" is the file you have chose to archive in (destination ) and "file" is the original non zipped file.